# Gradle tasks are not ordered properly

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I have two gradle tasks, named:

apiSpecGenerate - generates source files from OpenAPI

cleanupGenerated - manipulates with results of previous task (generated files should exist).

I added second task as finalizer for first task, that it is invoked after first task finishes.  But in fact, first task considered finished without producing anything, and second task failed, because generated files not exist.

first task:

```
val apiSpecGenerateTask = tasks.register("apiSpecGenerate") {
    println("!!!!!! GENERATE BEGIN !!!!!!")
    description = "Generate a cleaned api spec."
    dependsOn(openApiGenerateTaskName)
    openApiGenerationTaskNames.forEach { name -> dependsOn(tasks.findByName(name)) }
    println("!!!!!! GENERATE END !!!!!!")
}
```

second task (finalizer)

```
val cleanupGeneratedFilesTask = tasks.register("cleanupGenerated") {
    //dependsOn("apiSpecGenerate")
    println("!!!!!! CLEANUP BEGIN !!!!!!")

    project.delete(
        files("$generatedDtosFolder/org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable.kt"),
        files("$generatedDtosFolder/org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl.kt")
    )
    val dir = files("$generatedApiFolder/ControllerApi.kt")
    //.....
    println("!!!!!! CLEANUP END !!!!!!")
}
```

this doesn't work!

```
apiSpecGenerateTask {
    finalizedBy(cleanupGeneratedFilesTask)
}
```

result:

```
./gradlew  apiSpecGenerate
!!!!!! GENERATE BEGIN !!!!!!
!!!!!! GENERATE END !!!!!!
!!!!!! CLEANUP BEGIN !!!!!!

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':apiSpecGenerate'.
> Could not create task ':cleanupGenerated'.
   > /.../generated/api/ControllerApi.kt (No such file or directory)
```

but if I remove this dependency , apiSpecGenerate produces result.
it looks like task cleanupGenerated trying to access directory before it is actually generated.
How to tell Gradle wait for the actual task finished?

It doesn't work in the same command line invocation either:
second task does nothing.  It finishes before actual code generation started:
./gradlew  apiSpecGenerate cleanupGenerated

```
./gradlew  apiSpecGenerate cleanupGenerated
!!!!!! GENERATE BEGIN !!!!!!
!!!!!! GENERATE END !!!!!!
!!!!!! CLEANUP BEGIN !!!!!!
!!!!!! CLEANUP END !!!!!!

> Task :openApiGenerate
################################################################################
# Thanks for using OpenAPI Generator.                                          #
# Please consider donation to help us maintain this project                  #
# https://opencollective.com/openapi_generator/donate                          #
################################################################################
Successfully generated code to /projectdir/build/openapi-generated
```

it only works, if I separate these tasks by different command invocations:

./gradlew  apiSpecGenerate

./gradlew  cleanupGenerated

Comment: The stack is ordered in reverse. Bottom most message is the cause:
`> /.../generated/api/ControllerApi.kt (No such file or directory)` This file is either not created, not accessible in the scope, or otherwise not a valid parameter of `files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
tasks.register("myTask") {
   // do some configuration
   // this code will run in the configuration phase if the task is to be run
}
```

the code inside the braces is *configuring* the task, not specifying the *action* that takes place when the task is run.

If that task is to be run, then that code will run during the [project configuration phase](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases). The task action, however, is the task code that runs during the project execution phase. Naturally, the configuration phase takes place before the execution phase, and you do not want to mix these up.

There are different ways to specify the task action, but the easiest is to use a `doLast` inside the configuration block (see [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_registration)):

```
tasks.register("myTask") {
   doLast {
      // specify code to run when myTask is run
      // this code will run in the project execution phase, if the task is run
   }
}
```

So your finalizer task needs to look something like this:

```
val cleanupGeneratedFilesTask = tasks.register("cleanupGenerated") {
   doLast {   
      project.delete(
         files("$generatedDtosFolder/org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable.kt"),
         files("$generatedDtosFolder/org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl.kt")
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, doLast solved the trick. Perfect answer!

Comment: Pleased to hear it :) If you could accept the answer when you get a moment that would be appreciated